# Pros and Cons of two different ISP connection Model

Tags: cisco, router, isp, adsl

I have seen two different models to connect My Server to cloud.

Model 1:

```
 DNS   ------|
             |---ISP_Router---Cloud----DSL Modem---Office_Router---Switch---My_Own_Web_Server
Google ------|                     RJ11          (Gigabit Router)
```

Model 2:

```
 DNS   ------|
             |---ISP_Router---Cloud---------Office_Router---Switch---My_Own_Web_Server
Google ------|                       RJ11  (Gigabit Router)
```

Here is the First Model, Cloud has connected with DSL Modem with RJ11 Cable and DSL Modem connected to my Office Router with Ethernet Cable. But in the Second Model, RJ11 cable directly has connected from Cloud to Office Router with RJ11 Cable.

My Question is, what is the necessity of Model 2? Inserting DSL Modem between Cloud and Office Router as Model 1, will it be affect my Gigabit Ethernet Capacity? I am not a system Admin guy. But When I see this two models, I just curious to know about Pros and Cons of this two Models.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you have a separate modem comes down to a few factors, and performance is very unlikely to be one of them.

- Separate units are easier to maintain if you have to change one for any reason
- But usually the modems are very cheaply made and their power supplies are even lower quality
- Built-in modems are guaranteed to have no interfacing issues
- The built-in modems of professional routers give you very good diagnostic information; typical ISP-supplied modems normally only have an "internet good" LED

For my clients, I normally remove the external modem if only for wiring reasons.